# Player com ádio enviado pelo usuário

Tags: html5, input, áudio

Boa tarde moçada!
Estou com uma página que possui uma área que o usuário precisa adicionar áudios personalizados em cada player. Para a finalidade que preciso, uma playlist não seria tão eficaz. Precisaria ser realmente um áudio para cada player. Há alguma maneira simples de fazer isso usando input, talvez?
Estou utilizando o player padrão html5:

```html
<audio class="borda-player" src="audios/nas-maos-do-oleiro-pb.mp3" controls></audio>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Thalles você quer trocar o src dinamicamente? Poderia ser com um campo input text no evento onblur dele. Você está utilizando nesse projeto jquery?

Comment: Boa noite Rafael! Até então apenas HTML/CSS.

Comment: Mas nem um javascript puro? Com javascript tem jeito!

Comment: É possível fazer adicionando o evento [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended) com o JS.

Comment: experimenta isso http://kithomepage.com/sos/reproduzir-player.htm

Comment: Léo, é exatamente isso! tentei alterar o "input text" para "input file" pra upar o arquivo em vez de url, mas não tive sucesso. Poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Você quer que o usuário envie o arquivo para o servidor e seja reproduzido?

Comment: Isso mesmo! Exatamente! :D

Comment: Só com javascript, HTML/CSS não é possivel, seu servidor dá suporte a PHP?

Comment: Se você tem servidor que dá suporte a PHP tenho esse modelo http://kithomepage.com/upload_img/upload.html

Comment: Opa Léo! É isso mesmo que tava procurando!! Valeu irmão!!